# Facing error with BCP utility?

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I am getting the following error:

```
SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Unable to open BCP host data-file
NULL
```

while using this bcp utility

```
bcp "select * from database1.dbo.table1" queryout "c:\result.txt" -c -S10.10.10.100\dev -Usa -P123456 -t!
```

Please check.

Answer (score 1):

I have gotten that error before when my output file was not able to be accessed.  Make sure that you can write to C:\, or the file does not already exist.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this from the command prompt? I used to get the same error. To resolve it, I would browse to the directory i wanted, in this case "C:\" and I would call:

```
bcp "select * from database1.dbo.table1" queryout "result.txt" -c -S10.10.10.100\dev -Usa -P123456 -t!
```

Notice I removed the "C:\". I am not sure why this works but this removed the error for me.

Comment: You can use absolute path, and run from anywhere.  This is a permissions issue, or a file already exist error.

Answer (score 0):

1. Start xp_cmdshell from  SQL Server Surface Area Configuration

Comment: He's using the lower case `-t` to specify the field terminator.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that c:\result.txt is not open by you or anyone else.